# Plex: set up a new website

Tags: plesk

I am very new to Plex (on a virtual server by 1and1). I want to a add a second website project to the server.

I currently have one website which was set up after installation on this virtual server and two domains pointing to it and all great.

Now I want to add a second website. I have the option to add a new domain where I choose "In a separate webspace" but for some reason I do not get the option to "click ok" or like finish that process, what could be the problem? Would that be the right approach?

Comment: Are you sure your account allows more than 1 site?

Comment: fixed it: the solution was:
Under plesk apparence change view to "nterface provider"

Comment: @StnBnu post your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

the solution is: Under "Plesk Apparence" change view to "interface provider" - thus you get the menu from which you can add more domains and webspace. That is not possible in the "Power User" view.